# Using output of `git diff --name-only` for file names with non-ASCII characters

Tags: bash, git, utf-8

The output of `git diff --name-only` is not very useful for file names that are not ASCII.  Example:

```sh
git init
echo Germany > Düsseldorf.txt
echo Mexico > Cancún.txt
git add *.txt

while read f
    do cat "$f"
done < <(git diff --cached --name-only)
```

This results in the following output:

```
cat: '"Canc303272n.txt"': No such file or directory
cat: '"D303274sseldorf.txt"': No such file or directory
```

How can I obtain a listing of the staged files that's useful for further processing?

Comment: Try: `while IFS= read -r f`

Comment: Have a look at [`git diff`‘s `-z` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--z).

Comment: @anubhava That's only part of the solution – KamilCuk's answer below adds the missing bits to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I obtain a listing of the staged files that's useful for further processing?

Use a zero separated stream.

```
git diff -z --cached --name-only |
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
   cat "$f"
done
```

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Anyway, with just `cat`, then: `git diff -z --cached --name-only | xargs -0 cat`.

Comment: Thanks – the `xargs` alternative looks even nicer.

Comment: Note that if you can't deal with `'\0'`-separated text, `git -c core.quotepath=false diff ...` will reduce the set of characters that get quoted. The `-z` method is still preferable whenever possible though.